# how to filter array object using object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have a  filtering group js object like this :

```
 let filter = {
generalFilter:[
    {key: "connected", value: true},
    {key: "connected", value: false}
],
locationFilter:[
    {key: "deviceLocation", value: "def"},
     {key: "deviceLocation", value: "abc"}
],
paymentMethodsFilter:[
    {key: "devicePaymentMethods", value: "ab"}
]

}
```

and the main array like this:

```
const devices = [{
    deviceLocation: {
      label: "abc",
      value: "abc"
    },
    deviceName: "test7",
    devicePaymentMethods: [{
      label: "ab",
      value: "ab"
    }, {
      label: "cd",
      value: "cd"
    }, {
      label: "ef",
      value: "ef"
    }],
    deviceType: "iPad",
    id: "001",
    connected: true,
    enabled: true,
  },
  {
    deviceLocation: {
      label: "def",
      value: "def"
    },
    deviceName: "test4",
    devicePaymentMethods: [{
      label: "ab",
      value: "ab"
    }, {
      label: "cd",
      value: "cd"
    }],
    deviceType: "iPad",
    id: "004",
    connected: false,
    enabled: false,
  }
];
```

how can I filter this devices array using filter object?
this is what I tried but it doesn't work

```
devices.filter((device) => {
    let shouldKeep = new Array(3)
    shouldKeep.fill(0) //fills the array with 0, meaning no filter groups has passed yet
    for(let filterGroupIndex in filter) {// Loop through each filter group in filter
        let filterGroup = filter[filterGroupIndex]
        for(let filterObject in filterGroup) { //Loop through
            if(filterGroup[filterObject].key in device && device[filterGroup[filterObject].key] === filterGroup[filterObject].value) {
                shouldKeep[filterGroupIndex] = 1 //Set current filterGroup to 1, meaning it has passed the filter
                break; // At least one value in that filter group is true, skip to next filter group
            }
        }
    }

    if(shouldKeep.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) >= filter.length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false
})
```

sometimes this filter object can be empty when its empty it should return full array without filter main array. what is the best approach to do this? I'm not sure about this maybe there is another solution for this. please help me

the default filter object is like this

```
let filter = {
    generalFilter:[],
    locationFilter:[],
    paymentMethodsFilter:[]

    }
```

the user can add an object to that filter array I'm using react hooks 
for example

```
 let filter = {
generalFilter:[
    {key: "connected", value: true},
    {key: "connected", value: false}
],
locationFilter:[],
        paymentMethodsFilter:[]}
```

then we have to check both connected: false and connected: true  match data in the main array (if data has connected: true in the main array  then it will show and also if data has connected: false it will show)

for this type of filter

```
let filter = {
generalFilter:[
    {key: "connected", value: true},
    {key: "connected", value: false}
],
locationFilter:[
    {key: "deviceLocation", value: "def"},
     {key: "deviceLocation", value: "abc"}
],
paymentMethodsFilter:[
    {key: "devicePaymentMethods", value: "ab"}
]

}
```

result should be

```
result =[{
    deviceLocation: {
      label: "abc",
      value: "abc"
    },
    deviceName: "test7",
    devicePaymentMethods: [{
      label: "ab",
      value: "ab"
    }, {
      label: "cd",
      value: "cd"
    }, {
      label: "ef",
      value: "ef"
    }],
    deviceType: "iPad",
    id: "001",
    connected: true,
    enabled: true,
  },
  {
    deviceLocation: {
      label: "def",
      value: "def"
    },
    deviceName: "test4",
    devicePaymentMethods: [{
      label: "ab",
      value: "ab"
    }, {
      label: "cd",
      value: "cd"
    }],
    deviceType: "iPad",
    id: "004",
    connected: false,
    enabled: false,
  }
];
```

because u can see in filter connected:true and connected :false and  deviceLocation with def and abc and also devicePaymentMethods is ab

it's mean I want all devices with connected true and connected false with location abc and def and paymetmethod ab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check comments for explanation.

```js
const filter = {
    generalFilter: [
        {key: "connected", value: true},
        {key: "connected", value: false}
    ],
    locationFilter: [
        {key: "deviceLocation", value: "def"},
        {key: "deviceLocation", value: "abc"}
    ],
    paymentMethodsFilter: [
        {key: "devicePaymentMethods", value: "ab"}
    ]
};

const parsedFilter = {};

/**
  converting filter into a hashmap with a filter as a Key and value as an 
  array of possible values.
  
  parsedFilter looks like this
 {"connected":[true,false],"deviceLocation":["def","abc"],"paymentOption":["ab"]}

  now we can easily check if any value is present in the filter.

   **/
const filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);

filterKeys.forEach((filterKey) => {
    if (Array.isArray(filter[filterKey])) {
        filter[filterKey].forEach((filterItem) => {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(parsedFilter, filterItem.key)) {
                parsedFilter[filterItem.key].push(filterItem.value);
            } else {
                parsedFilter[filterItem.key] = [filterItem.value];
            }
        });
    }
});


const devices = [
    {
        deviceLocation: {
            label: "abc",
            value: "abc"
        },
        deviceName: "test7",
        devicePaymentMethods: [
            {
                label: "ab",
                value: "ab"
            }, {
                label: "cd",
                value: "cd"
            }, {
                label: "ef",
                value: "ef"
            }],
        deviceType: "iPad",
        id: "001",
        connected: true,
        enabled: true,
    }
];

const result = [];

/**
  Looping through each device and check if that key is present in the 
  parsedFilter.
  
  if true: check for typeof value for that device key.
           if Object: then check if it is present in the array of not for the 
                      givem deviceKey in parsedFilter.
           if Array: then loop through each item and check if it is present 
                     in the parsedFilter for the given deviceKey
           if Number, string, boolean: Check if is present in the 
                      parsedFilter for the given deviceKey

  if false: simply add it to the result.
**/
if (Array.isArray(devices)) {
    devices.forEach((device) => {
        const keys = Object.keys(device);
        const resultDeviceObj = {};

        keys.forEach((key) => {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(parsedFilter, key)) {
                if (typeof device[key] === "object" && parsedFilter[key].includes(device[key].value)) {
                    resultDeviceObj[key] = device[key];
                } else if (Array.isArray(device[key])) {
                    const arrayResult = [];

                    device[key].forEach((item) => {
                        if (parsedFilter[key].includes(item.value)) {
                            arrayResult.push(item);
                        }
                    });

                    resultDeviceObj[key] = arrayResult;
                } else if(parsedFilter[key].includes(device[key])) {
                    resultDeviceObj[key] = device[key];
                }
            } else {
                resultDeviceObj[key] = device[key];
            }
        });

        result.push(resultDeviceObj);
    });
}

console.log("result", result);
```

> Edit
>
> ```js
> const filter = {
>     generalFilter: [{key: "connected", value: true}],
>     locationFilter: [{key: "deviceLocation", value: "abcd"}],
>     paymentMethodsFilter: [{key: "devicePaymentMethods", value: "ab"}]
> };
>
> const parsedFilter = {};
>
> const filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);
>
> filterKeys.forEach((filterKey) => {
>     if (Array.isArray(filter[filterKey])) {
>         filter[filterKey].forEach((filterItem) => {
>             if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(parsedFilter, filterItem.key)) {
>                 parsedFilter[filterItem.key][filterItem.value] = filterItem.value;
>             } else {
>                 parsedFilter[filterItem.key] = {
>                     [filterItem.value]: filterItem.value
>                 }
>             }
>         });
>     }
> });
>
> //{"connected":{"true": true,"false": "false"},"deviceLocation":{"def": "def","abc": "abc"},"paymentOption":{"ab": "ab"}}
> const devices = [{
>     deviceLocation: {
>         label: "abc",
>         value: "abc"
>     },
>     deviceName: "test7",
>     devicePaymentMethods: [{
>         label: "ab",
>         value: "ab"
>     }, {
>         label: "cd",
>         value: "cd"
>     }, {
>         label: "ef",
>         value: "ef"
>     }],
>     deviceType: "iPad",
>     id: "001",
>     connected: true,
>     enabled: true,
> },
>     {
>         deviceLocation: {
>             label: "def",
>             value: "def"
>         },
>         deviceName: "test4",
>         devicePaymentMethods: [{
>             label: "ab",
>             value: "ab"
>         }, {
>             label: "cd",
>             value: "cd"
>         }],
>         deviceType: "iPad",
>         id: "004",
>         connected: false,
>         enabled: false,
>     }
> ];
>
> const result = [];
>
> const isObject = function (a) {
>     return a.constructor.toString().indexOf("Object") !== -1;
> };
>
> if (Array.isArray(devices)) {
>     devices.forEach((device) => {
>             const keys = Object.keys(device);
>             let isValid = true;
>             for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
>                 const key = keys[i];
>
>                 if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(parsedFilter, key)) {
>                     if (isObject(device[key]) &&
>                         !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(parsedFilter[key], device[key].value)) {
>                         isValid = false;
>                         break;
>                     } else if (Array.isArray(device[key])) {
>                         isValid = false;
>                         for (let j = 0; j < device[key].length; j++) {
>                             const item = device[key][j];
>                             if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(parsedFilter[key], item.value)) {
>                                 isValid = true;
>                                 break;
>                             }
>                         }
>
>                         if (!isValid) {
>                             break;
>                         }
>                     } else if (typeof device[key] === "boolean" &&
>                         !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(parsedFilter[key], device[key])) {
>                         isValid = false;
>                         break;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>
>             if (isValid) {
>                 result.push(device);
>             }
>         }
>     );
> }
>
>
> console.log("result", result)
> ```

Comment: `paymentOption` key in filter points to `devicePaymentMethods` in device's Object? for rest, there are 1:1 mapping but not for paymentOption

Comment: I added more details and sorry for paymentOption I changed it. I checked ur code even i changed filter object into this const filter = {
    generalFilter: [
        {key: "connected", value: false}
    ],
    locationFilter: [
        
    ],
    paymentMethodsFilter: [
        
    ]
};   it returns same data result should be empty bc there is no data with connected: false in that devices array according to ur devices array

Comment: @nurwadula so there is `AND` condition between the filters?

Comment: Can you give an example with input and expected output?

Comment: yeah, there is AND condition between the filters sorry I did not mention that .my bad

Comment: i added expected output

Comment: Check my edits. I changed my parsedFilter's structure for a faster lookup

Comment: According to your result, there is `OR` condition between the values of the filter and `AND` condition between the filter types.

Comment: yeah but i tried this filter const filter = {
    generalFilter: [
        {key: "connected", value: true}
    ],
    locationFilter: [
        {key: "deviceLocation", value: "abcd"}
    ],
    paymentMethodsFilter: [
        {key: "devicePaymentMethods", value: "ab"}
    ]
};  

the result should be empty for this filter bc there no deviceLocatation with abcd in the main devices array

Comment: yeah, I got an empty array for your filter. Did you try the second one?

Comment: the problem is only with the deviceLocation others are working fine

Comment: I updated my filter with yours. check the output. if still not working then create a jsFiddle and share it with me

Comment: omg I don't what is wrong . I used  https://repl.it/languages/nodejs to compile ur code it returns an array with values on that site but here it returns an empty array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208937/discussion-between-abhishek-and-nurwadula).

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more what you are trying to do. It is very unclear from your question.

In general you would do something like this if you want to filter by device location.

```
devices.filter(device=>device.deviceLocation.label==="abc")
```

I hope this example will help you figure out the rest.

Comment: I wanna get  the  data that match all conditions in the filter object
if i use this  devices.filter(device=>device.deviceLocation.label==="abc")   it only check one condition

Comment: const filtered_values=devices.filter(device=>
              {
                return device.connected===filter.generalFilter[0].value ||
                device.connected===filter.generalFilter[1].value &&
                device.deviceLocation.value===filter.locationFilter[0].value ||
                device.deviceLocation.value===filter.locationFilter[1].value &&
                device.devicePaymentMethods.value===filter.paymentMethodsFilter[0].value
              }
             )